# Django views.py Version of SQL Join with Multi Table Query

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql, django

Need some help with Django version of SQL multi table query. The query is using 3 tables to retrieve restaurant name, address from `Restaurants table` and Cuisine type from `Cuisinetypes table`. All based on cuisine name that is passed through URL and the cuisine ID  is stored in Cuisine table.

**Models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='name', blank=True)
    slugname = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name="restaurants")
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name="restaurants")
    hood = models.ForeignKey('Hood', null=True, blank=True, related_name="restaurants")
    listingrole = models.ForeignKey('Listingrole', related_name="restaurants")
    cuisine_types = models.ManyToManyField('Cuisinetype', null=True, blank=True, related_name="restaurants")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'restaurant'

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='city')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    switch = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default='1')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'city'

class Cuisinetype(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='cuisine', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    switch = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default='1')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuisinetype'

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='location', blank=False, null=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name="locations")
    switch = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default='1')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'location'

class Hood(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='hood')
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name='hoods')
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name='hoods')
    switch = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default='1')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'hood'    

class Listingrole(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='listingrole', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    switch = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default='1')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'listingrole'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^cuisine/(?P<cuisine>[-\w]+)/$', 'views.cuisinesearch'),
```

**views.py**

```
def cuisinesearch(request, name='unknown'):
name = name.replace('-', ' ').capitalize()
return render_to_response('cuisinesearch.html', 
                          {'cuisinesearch': Restaurant.objects.filter(city_id=8, switch=1, listingrole__in=[1,2,3,4], cuisine_types__name=name)
                          .distinct().prefetch_related("cuisine_types").order_by('listingrole', 'displayorder')[:50] })
```

**HTML**

Also what would be the correct way to display the query?

```
{% for restaurant in cuisinesearch %}
<h2>{{ restaurant.name }}</h2>
<div class="location">{{ restaurant.location }}</div>
<h3>Cuisines:</h3>
<ul class="cuisines">{% for ct in restaurant.cuisine_types.all %}
<li>{{ ct.name }}</li>{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Most of the point of using Django is to do this kind of thing for you using its ORM, that is, using **models**, not executing arbitrary SQL. Please show your model code.

Comment: As per your request I added the Models. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be trying to force Django to make the database a certain way instead of just letting it do what it is good at. Why don't you have a look at the Django documentation concerning how it handles [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and adjust your models accordingly...

Comment: I'm just working with what I already have from another project and it is almost impossible to start from scratch as I already have over 100+ tables with data.

Comment: Django's ORM depends on you specifying, e.g., `ManyToManyField` in your models so Django knows what is going on. If you are not going to tell it these kinds of things, then you may as well stick to [executing your already designed SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) and hoping for the best, or simply not using Django.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)?

Comment: I have and thats exactly how I loaded to DB structure into the Models

Comment: FYI I have updated the original post with the Models.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, those are some unclear table and field names, but best I can tell that query would look something like:

```
(Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, 
     cuisine__cuisinetype__cuisine="Italian").distinct().order_by('name')[:20])
```

But unless you're locked into that database schema, your models would look better as:

```
class CuisineType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuisinetype'

class Restaurants(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey("City", null=True, blank=True) # Apparently defined elsewhere. Should be part of location?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.ForeignKey("Location", null=True, blank=True) # Apparently defined elsewhere.
    cuisines = models.ManyToManyField(CuisineType)
```

Then the query would be more like:

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, cuisines__name="Italian").order_by('name')[:20]
```

---

OK, let's walk through your query, assuming no changes to your code. We'll start with the subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT res_id FROM cuisine 
        JOIN    cuisinetype ON cuisine.cuisineid = cuisinetype.`cuisineid`
        WHERE   cuisinetype.`cuisine` = 'Italian'
```

We look at the WHERE clause and see we need a JOIN. To do a join, you must declare a relational field in one of the joined models (Django will add a reverse relation, which we should name). So we're matching up `cuisine.cuisineid` with `cuisinetype.cuisineid. That's some horrible naming.

That's a many-to-many relation, so we need a `ManyToManyField`. Well, looking at the `Cuisine` model, it's really the joining table for this M2M. Django expects a joining table to have two `ForeignKey` fields, one pointing to each side of the joint. Normally it'll create this for you to save sanity. Apparently you're not that lucky. So you have to manually hook it up.

It seems the "GID" field is a (useless) ID field for the record, so let's assume it's auto-increment integer. (To be sure, check the CREATE TABLE commands.) Now we can rewrite the `Cuisine` model into something approaching sane:

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
    cuisinegid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='CuisineGID')
    cuisineid = models.ForeignKey("Cuisinetype", null=True, 
        db_column='CuisineID', blank=True)
    res_id = models.ForeignKey("Restaurant", null=True, db_column='Res_ID', 
        blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuisine'
```

The model names are quoted because the models haven't been defined yet (they're later in the file). Now there's no requirement that the Django field names match the column names, so let's change them to something more readable. The record ID field is usually just named `id`, and foreign keys are usually named after what they relate to:

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='CuisineGID')
    cuisine_type = models.ForeignKey("CuisineType", null=True, 
        db_column='CuisineID', blank=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey("Restaurant", null=True, db_column='Res_ID', 
        blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuisine'
```

OK, we're done defining our joint table. While we're at this, let's apply the same stuff to our `Cuisinetype` model. Note the corrected camel-case class name:

```
class CuisineType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='CuisineID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='Cuisine', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuisinetype'
```

So we finally get to our `Restaurant` model. Note that the name is *singular;* an object only represents one record.

I notice that it lacks any `dp_table` or `db_column` stuff, so I'm going out on a limb and guessing Django is creating it. That means we can let it create the `id` field for us and we can omit it from our code. (If that's not the case, then we just add it like with the other models. But you really shouldn't have a nullable record ID.) And this is where our cuisine type `ManyToManyField` lives:

```
class Restaurants(models.Model):
    city_id = models.ForeignKey(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(null=True, blank=True)
    cuisine_types = models.ManyToManyField(CuisineType, through=Cuisine,
        null=True, blank=True)
```

Note that the name for the M2M field is plural, since that relation leads to multiple records.

One more thing we will want to add to this model is names for the reverse relationships. In other words, how to go from the other models back to `Restaurant`. We do this by adding `related_name` parameters. It's not unusual for them to be the same.

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    city_id = models.ForeignKey(null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name="restaurants")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(null=True, blank=True, 
        related_name="restaurants")
    cuisine_types = models.ManyToManyField(CuisineType, through=Cuisine,
        null=True, blank=True, related_name="restaurants")
```

Now we're finally set. So let's look at your query:

```
SELECT  restaurants.`name`, restaurants.`address`, cuisinetype.`cuisine`
FROM    restaurants
JOIN    cuisinetype ON cuisinetype.cuisineid = restaurants.`cuisine`
WHERE   city_id = 8 AND restaurants.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT res_id FROM cuisine 
        JOIN    cuisinetype ON cuisine.cuisineid = cuisinetype.`cuisineid`
        WHERE   cuisinetype.`cuisine` = 'Italian')
ORDER BY restaurants.`name`
LIMIT 20
```

Since this is `FROM restaurants`, we'll start with that model's default object manager, `objects`:

```
Restaurant.objects
```

The `WHERE` clause in this case is a `filter()` call, so we add it for the first term:

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8)
```

You can have wither a primary key value or a `City` object on the right hand side of that term. The rest of the query gets more complex, though, because it needs the `JOIN`. A join in Django just looks like dereferencing through the relation field. In a query, that means joining the relevant field names with a double underscore:

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, cuisine_type__name="Italian")
```

Django knows which fields to join on because that's declared in the `Cuisine` table which is pulled in by the `through=Cuisine` parameter in `cuisine_types`. it also knows to do a subquery because you're going through an M2M relation.

So that gets us SQL equivalent to:

```
SELECT  restaurants.`name`, restaurants.`address`
FROM    restaurants
WHERE   city_id = 8 AND restaurants.id IN (
        SELECT res_id FROM cuisine 
        JOIN    cuisinetype ON cuisine.cuisineid = cuisinetype.`cuisineid`
        WHERE   cuisinetype.`cuisine` = 'Italian')
```

Halfway there. Now we need `SELECT DISTINCT` so we don't get multiple copies of the same record:

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, cuisine_type__name="Italian").distinct()
```

And you need to pull in the cuisine types for display. Turns out that the query you have is inefficient there, because it only gets you to the join table and you need to run further queries to get the related `CuisineType` records. Guess what: Django has you covered.

```
(Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, cuisine_type__name="Italian").distinct()
    .prefetch_related("cuisine_types"))
```

Django will run two queries: one like yours to get the joint IDs, and one more to get the related `CuisineType` records. Then accesses via the query result don't need to go back to the database.

The last two things are the ordering:

```
(Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, cuisine_type__name="Italian").distinct()
    .prefetch_related("cuisine_types").order_by("name"))
```

And the `LIMIT`:

```
(Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, cuisine_type__name="Italian").distinct()
    .prefetch_related("cuisine_types").order_by("name")[:20])
```

And there's your query (and the related query) packed into two lines of Python. Mind you, at this point, the query hasn't even been executed. You have to put it in something, like a template, before it does anything:

```
def cuisinesearch(request, cuisine):
    return render_to_response('cuisinesearch.html', {
        'restaurants': (Restaurant.objects.filter(city=8, 
             cuisine_type__name="Italian").distinct()
             .prefetch_related("cuisine_types").order_by("name")[:20])
        })
```

Template:

```
{% for restaurant in cuisinesearch %}
<h2>{{ restaurant.name }}</h2>
<div class="location">{{ restaurant.location }}</div>
<h3>Cuisines:</h3>
<ul class="cuisines">{% for ct in restaurant.cuisine_types.all %}
<li>{{ ct.name }}</li>{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the original post with the Models.py file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your in depth response. Based on you response I have realized that I need to start from scratch and re-do the models. Based on you suggestions, I re-designed the Models and posted the models new version in my original post. I would really appreciate if you can take a look and provide feedback before I run the "syncdb". Thanks again!

Comment: You can remove every instance of `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')`; Django creates these for you automatically. The only time you have to write it out is if `db_column` is something besides `id`.

Comment: 2) Don't suffix field names with `_id`. Django puts that in the column name on its own for `ForeignKey` fields. 3) What is `listingrole` supposed to be? Is it a one-to-many or many-to-many relation? 4) Remove the `L` suffixes from the `max_length` fields; there's zero need for them. 5) Unless you're interfacing to existing tables, don't use `db_table` or `db_column`. 6) Related names for `ForeignKey` fields should be plurals, because they can return any number of records. For example, the related names in the  FKs for `Hood` should be `hoods`.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. I included the field mostly for visual reasons. As the per th ManyToManyField, do I have it right or do I need to include the through='' value?. Thanks again, you help is much appreciated!

Comment: 7) `blank=False, null=False` is the default; don't add them. 8) It's nice to set a default `ordering` in `class Meta` for each model.

Comment: Listingrole is for distinguishing types of listing roles such as "Partner, Trial, Free Listing" etc. It is a one-to-many value.

Comment: You can omit the `through` parameter and its model if you're not using an existing join table. Django will create the join table for you. (The real purpose for `through` models is so you can add information to the M2M relationships; for example a M2M table relating users to each other could use a `through` table to record the type of relationship.)

Comment: So long as a `Restaurant` has only one `ListingRole` (not more), it's a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Also as per "Hood". It is an optional value in the Restaurant table so is null=True and blank=True required?

Comment: Yes, those are required.

Comment: Good news! I was able to figure it out and its all working now. The updated view is posted in my OP. Once again, I'm extremely grateful for all your help! God bless you! Thanks again!