# Django Models.py Database Design Feedback

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312873/django-views-py-version-of-sql-join-with-multi-table-query) and feedback I received I have redesigned my Models and need some feedback before I run the "*syncdb*".

My concerns are mostly *ForeignKeys* and the one *ManyToManyField* in the Restaurant table. Should also the ManyTomany field have the *through=''* value and what the value should be?

Any feedback is appreciated!

**Models**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='name', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True)
    city_id = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name="restaurant_city")
    location_id = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name="restaurant_location")
    hood_id = models.ForeignKey('Hood', null=True, blank=True, related_name="restaurant_hood")
    listingrole_id = models.ForeignKey('Listingrole', related_name="restaurant_listingrole")
    cuisine_types = models.ManyToManyField('Cuisinetype', null=True, blank=True, related_name="restaurant_cuisinetype")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'restaurant'

class City(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='city')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='state', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'city'

class Cuisinetype(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='cuisine', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cuisinetype'

class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='location', blank=False, null=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name="location_city")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'location'

class Hood(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='hood')
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name='hood_city')
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name='hood_location')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'hood'    

class Listingrole(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, db_column='listingrole', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'listingrole'
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Having into account the concept and meaning of `coisine_types` you don't have to make the relationship using `through` keyword. You use it (mostly) when there is some information about the relation it self.

According Django documentation:

> The most common use for this option is when you want to associate extra data with a many-to-many relationship.

See explanation here: [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)